# Popular Combobox DataGrid Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um datagrid(c# windows forms) que preciso usar para edição e estou populando com informações vindas do banco de dados de uma tabela chamada "custos"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os campos Plano de contas e Centro Custo vem preenchido com informações armazenadas na tabela "custos".
Tenho outras duas tabelas (PlanoConta e Centro Custo).
A minha idéia é clicar em plano conta ou centro de custos e trazer os dados da respectivas tabelas.
Setei o campo conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao clicar no campo ele não me traz os dados da tabela PlanoContas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Você checou se o seu planoContasBindingSource está sendo populado?

Comment: Olá boar tarde, esta sim... :(

Comment: Como você popula ele? Se ele for populado depois de ter sido atribuído ao `DataSource` do combo você precisa chamar o método `ResetBindings`(se não me engano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui solucionar!
Estou populando via codigo conforme abaixo:

```
        FinanceiroDbContext db = new FinanceiroDbContext();

        PlanoConta.ValueMember = "Nome";
        PlanoConta.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        PlanoConta.DataSource = db.PlanoContas.ToList();
        CentroCusto.ValueMember = "Nome";
        CentroCusto.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        CentroCusto.DataSource = db.CentroCusto.ToList();
        GridRateio.DataSource = db.ExtratoCentroCusto.Where(x => x.NControl == ids).ToList();
```

O que fiz, foi popular o combobox antes de popular o datagrid!
Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Usando `BindingSource` precisaria criar um para cada ComboBox. Um `planoContasBidingSource` e outro `centroCustoBidingSource`, carregá-los com os dados e configurar-los para serem o `DataSource` de sua respectiva combobox, conforme você fez na imagem. Falta carregar os dados, pelo que entendi.

Pra essa configuração funcionar é necessário popular os `BindingSource` com os dados das suas tabelas. Se você postar os métodos que utiliza para realizar as queries fica mais fácil de te ajudarmos! Tente retornar `IList<T>` do seus métodos de query no banco para poder atribuir os resultados aos BidingSource com mais facilidade.